# Creating a monopoly command game in Objective C

Tags: objective-c, arrays, oop, constructor, overloading

I'm a software application development student going into my final year where we have been given free reign of choice of languages. Being an Apple Fanboy - my choice naturally was Objective-C.

As a student - we all learned Java, and our OOP module: we had to build a text based monopoly game.

In Java it is quite easy to do - especially given that you have Constructors and overloaded constructors. In Objective C - overloaded and constructors aren't as easy.

I realize there is a way to do it etc with init and things but i'm still learning and it's rather hard to try and get the hang of some of the OOP on Objective C.

As you can guess - i'm trying to basically port over the Java code to Objective C to get my hands in on doing things the Apple Way. This is how i'm gonna spend my summer.

My question is the following:

**How do you use "overloaded inits"?**

My board for the monopoly in java is an array but with overloaded constructors as the object to fill those array:

```
public void board(){ //method to initialise the property objects

    board [0] = new Extras  ("Go",200,5);
    board [1] = new Property("Old Kent",80,6,0);
    board [2] = new Property("White Hall",100,10,0);
    board [3] = new Property("Fleet Street",120,12,0);
```

also - **how do you do this with NSArray/MutableArray?**

I've been wrecking my brain trying to figure it out - i'm still a newbie with objective C and software so please be gentle.

Thank you guys.

Comment: Overloaded inits are just another selector, e.g. `-initWithName:price:rent:`. You can append to arrays using `-addObject:`.

Comment: just make your own property class and init method...

Answer (score 2):

Inside your Property class, add a new initializer:

```
// designated initializer
- (id)initWithName:(NSString *)name price:(int)price rent:(int)rent
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        // Set your ivars here (e.g. _name = name;)
    }
    return self;
}
```

In an initializer, you should always call your superclass's designated initializer, check to see if it succeeded, and if so, code your own logic. You can then add convenience initializers that call this one:

```
- (id)init
{
    return [self initWithName:@"" price:0 rent:0];
}
```

In this case, you call your *own* designated initializer.

As mentioned by Richard J. Ross in the comments, you can use addObject: to add objects to an NSMutableArray.

```
NSMutableArray *board = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[board addObject: [[Property alloc] initWithName:@"Old Kent" price:80, rent:6]];
// and so on
```

You cannot add objects to a non-mutable NSArray.

Comment: Although you can not add objects to a non-mutable NSArray, you can create a new one that contains all of the existing objects and the new one by using something like `board = [board arrayByAddingObject:newObject];`.

Comment: Hi guys - thank you for your response. I'm still a tad confused though, - is there any possible chance you can explain the 2nd part to me?